# Battery Protection IC in Series

Tags: integrated-circuit, batteries

I want to make a project to protect each individual cells of 16 series battery pack. I have read some data sheets of battery protection IC's such as BQ29209DRBR,S-8261,AP9281 etc. None of them clearly explain If those IC can be used in series. In my humble opinion ,if voltage difference will stay same ,there will be no problem.
But I need to take thought from professionals. Here is How I think of connecting them
[image]
Sorry for my ugly schematic :)

Here is some more datasheets that I think It may work [R5432](https://www.e-devices.ricoh.co.jp/en/products/lithium_ion/r5432/r5432-ea.pdf),[BQ2947](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=bq2947&fileType=pdf)

Comment: Tere is an embedded schematic editor. Easy to learn without manual :-). Click cct diagram icon when editing. 7th from left above text. ||Provide data sheet link to ICs you think MAY work. What "protection" are you wanting - over charge, under discharge, short circuit, ...

Comment: is there anybody in there???

Comment: Echo: There is an embedded schematic editor. Easy to learn without manual :-). Click cct diagram icon when editing. 7th from left above text. ||Provide data sheet link to ICs you think MAY work. What "protection" are you wanting - over charge, under discharge, short circuit, ..

Comment: Echo: What "protection" are you wanting - over charge, under discharge, short circuit, ..  -> if you ignore questions designed to help understand your question better then there may indeed be nobody there.

Comment: Sorry If I was being rude. I want this prohect to have over charge ,under discharge protection. Your answer was so helpful .

Comment: Overcharge protection is "easy enough" as the voltage of each cell can be monitored and steps taken to remove charging current on a per cell basis. Overdischarge per cell is hard as if you removed a cell from a series string (which takes two FETs typically ) the spring voltage drops and so this is not suited to a parallel string arrangement. What you can do is stop discharging overall if any cell is dangerously low or send a warning if any cell is approaching a critical point.

Comment: I didn't see that as rude :-) - just not likely to get as many people helping if you don't provide as much information as you can "up front". I didn't look for the ICs which you gave names but not links for but they too may have examples in their data sheets re series connecting multiple ICs.  It's a common enough requirement and will usually be possible.

Comment: [**Possible relevance**](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-battery-management/713?k=battery+protection&k=&pkeyword=battery+protection&sv=0&pv36=77&pv36=87&pv36=82&pv36=80&sf=1&FV=ffe002c9%2C1b80520%2C1b8004b%2C1b80306&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ricoh [R5432V](https://www.e-devices.ricoh.co.jp/en/products/lithium_ion/r5432/r5432-ea.pdf) that you cite has an example on page 35 of two devices series chained to provide 7 cell protection. The method shown could be extended to more than two ICs.

The single IC ccts on pages 32 33 34 look relatively self contained so a series could stand on top of each other - but need redundant external FETs per cct group. The cct on p35 shows how to combine them in one case.

The TI [BQ2947](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2947.pdf) is only an over-voltage protector. The simplified cct on page 1 is very standalone except for the single fuse blowing MOSFET. (This could instead be a "charge disable" function.)  That feature could be extended to a group of series cct with a diode OR gate - each cct uses a diode and resistor to pull down the FET gate when active.

**____________________________**

**Overcharge protection** per cell in a series string is "easy enough" as the voltage of each cell can be monitored and steps taken to remove charging current on a per cell basis.

**Overdischarge per cell** is hard as if you removed a cell from a series string (which takes two FETs typically ) the string voltage drops and so this is not suited to a parallel string arrangement.

What you can do is

- Stop discharging overall if any cell is dangerously low or send a warning if any cell is approaching a critical point.
- Unusual (probably) - remove the string with the low voltage cell in it. Strings which have cells all above the limit will continue to discharge until each in turn 'drops out'. The maximium discharge capacity of the battery will also drop as strings are removed.